# Android app fails to run on startup with 1 activitiy and 1 class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to make an app wich loads images from flickr. To build this, I have an activity, which contains 1 fragment.

The activity layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@id/activity_main"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
        class="com.example.jonas.flickrfestival.MainActivityFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This layout is binded with the following activity class:

```
    package com.example.jonas.flickrfestival;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

The fragment layout: fragment_main

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtSearch" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Search photo&apos;s" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the binded class:
    package com.example.jonas.flickrfestival;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.jonas.flickrfestival.network.JsonHandler;

public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private String url;
    private Button btnFetch;
    private EditText txtSearch;

    public MainActivityFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        btnFetch = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        txtSearch = (EditText) container.findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);

        btnFetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                JsonHandler handler = new JsonHandler();
                handler.fetchImages(txtSearch.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}

Ok now the problem. If I run the application on my phone, it crashes immeddiately and I get following error output:

    >     > 08-10 11:11:35.959  29470-29470/com.example.jonas.flickrfestival
    >     > E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    >     >     Process: com.example.jonas.flickrfestival, PID: 29470
    >     >     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jonas.flickrfestival/com.example.jonas.flickrfestival.MainActivity}:
    >     > android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
    >     > inflating class fragment
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
    >     >             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    >     >             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
    >     >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    >     >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    >     >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    >     >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
    >     >      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
    >     >             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    >     >             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    >     >             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    >     >             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    >     >             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    >     >             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:401)
    >     >             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2197)
    >     >             at com.example.jonas.flickrfestival.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
    >     >             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
    >     >             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
    >     >             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    >     >             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
    >     >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    >     >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    >     >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    >     >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
    >     >      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View
    > android.view.View.findViewById(int)'
    >     > on a null object reference
    >     >             at com.example.jonas.flickrfestival.MainActivityFragment.onCreateView(MainActivityFragment.java:26)
    >     >             at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2062)
    >     >             at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
    >     >             at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1045)
    >     >             at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1147)
    >     >             at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2116)
    >     >             at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5369)
    >     >             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
    >     >             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    >     >             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    >     >             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    >     >             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    >     >             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:401)
    >     >             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2197)
    >     >             at com.example.jonas.flickrfestival.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
    >     >             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
    >     >             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
    >     >             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    >     >             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    >     >             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
    >     >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    >     >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    >     >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    >     >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

So if I check my code, the problem lines are in the fragment class:

```
    > btnFetch = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    >         txtSearch = (EditText) container.findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
```

So the container is null I think. But how can I get the layout items of the view?

Comment: Logcat error trace please?

Comment: You are trying to access a `Button` and an `EditText` which does not exist yet. See the example codes here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#BackStack

Comment: Fragment's view is not set yet so getVIew() fails . I presume you are accessing the getVIew() within the onCreateView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make some changes as below :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup mView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    btnFetch = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    txtSearch = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);

    btnFetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JsonHandler handler = new JsonHandler();
            handler.fetchImages(txtSearch.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    return mView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with removing `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` from fragment tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow as below:

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            viewInflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null);
            return viewInflate;
        }

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         Button  btnFetch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        Button txtSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
    }
```